# Svelte keep default prop value of a child component

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, svelte-component

I have component1 that takes `let text` as a prop and then component2 that does almost the same thing, but I'd like to keep component1 separate for better reusability.

So I wrapped the comp1 (`Child.svelte`) with comp2 (`Wrapper.svelte`). But how do I keep the default prop value of the Child component without writing it again?

here is an example:

```svelte
//Wrapper.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import Child from "./Child.svelte";
    export let text = 'hello world'; //need to type the default value again
</script>

<Child text={text} />
```

```svelte
//Child.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    export let text = 'hello world';
</script>

<p>{text}</p>
```

Comment: Why do you need this if you just `export let text;` in _Wrapper.svelte_ it will be undefined and use the default in the Child.

Comment: Because if the text prop has no default value and I don't assign that prop from the outside, there will be a typescript error: `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { text: string;}'.
  Property 'text' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ text: string; }'.ts(2322)`

Comment: In that case define the type as "string or undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @hackape and @Stephane Vanraes for your answers!

the answer from @hackape seems like the answer I was looking for, but It still throws this typescript error: `Property 'text' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ text: string; }'.ts(2322)` when I don't provide any value to Wrapper comp. from the outside.

I should have realised this earlier, but I combined both answers and came up with this:

```
//Wrapper.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import Child from "./Child.svelte";
    export let text: string = undefined;
</script>

<Child bind:text />
```

also works with `<Child text={text}/>`

I am relatively new to Stack Overflow, should I accept my or @hackapes answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use `bind:prop` to create a two way binding. Docs: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-bindings

```html
//Wrapper.svelte
<script lang="ts">
import Child from "./Child.svelte";
export let text: string
</script>

<Child bind:text />
```